# Class: Definition of an empty variable: etoolbox: problems of comparison

Tags: etoolbox, documentclass-writing, comparison

I'm writing my first class and I'm a bit in trouble with a behaviour of `etoolbox` macros that I don't understand at all. I tried to read response on the forum but I didn't get a clue.

I would like to, according to the option of the class, run a function (which one will set a presentation into the sheet).

I have four different presentations called with four options: prezC, prezE, prezG and prezL.

When I compile with `\documentclass[prezC]{test}` or with `[prezG]` or `[prezL]` everything is fine. However when I compile with `[prezE]` I can read into the logs:

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):    [prezE].
[...]
! Use of \prez doesn't match its definition.
\presentation #1->valeur=#1\ifdefstring
        {#1}{E}{\presentationE }{\ifdefstrin...
l.7 \begin{document}
```

Why? I don't understand why the behaviour is not the same with prezE and the others options.

- I tried to change `\ifdefstring` by others macros but none have worked.
- I tried to add `\string` in the definition of `\prez` doing `[\def\prez{\string E}]` and in the test doing `[\ifstrequal{#1}{\string E}{true}{false}]`

None of my attempt works.
Do you know the reason? Could you have any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Last,

running `latex -v` give me:

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.1
```

My class is:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{test}[2016/08/11 LaTeX class]

\global\def\prez%
\DeclareOption{prezE}{\def\prez{E}}
\DeclareOption{prezC}{\def\prez{C}}
\DeclareOption{prezG}{\def\prez{G}}
\DeclareOption{prezL}{\def\prez{L}}

\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginDocument{\presentation{\prez}}%

\newcommand{\presentationE}{Ceci est la prez E.}
\newcommand{\presentationC}{Ceci est la prez C.}
\newcommand{\presentationG}{Ceci est la prez G.}
\newcommand{\presentationL}{Ceci est la prez L.}

\newcommand{\presentation}[1]{%
valeur=#1%
\ifdefstring{#1}{E}{\presentationE}{%
\ifdefstring{#1}{C}{\presentationC}{%
\ifdefstring{#1}{G}{\presentationG}{%
\presentationL}}}}%
\endinput
%% End of file `test.cls'.
```

My main is basically:

```
\documentclass[prezE]{test}
%% 
\begin{document}
Test ok.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I change the title as it's just a problem of empty definition.
Thanks Stefan to have improved the format of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\global\def\prez%
\DeclareOption{prezE}
```

defines `\prez` so it has to be followed by `\DeclareOption` and expands to `prezE`

I guess you intended

```
\global\def\prez{}%
\DeclareOption{prezE}
```

to define `\prez` to be empty, and to declare a `prezE` option.

Comment: Many thanks David. I didn't know that empty curly brackets were mandatory. I'll remember it for next time !!